# CSVHelper - Mapped single class with subclasses, but getting multiple rows returned

Tags: c#, csv, csvhelper

I am trying to use CsvHelper to parse a file, which has three horizontal sections in it, into a single, nested C# class.  I expected to get a single row returned from the file, but I am getting multiple rows and incorrect data.  My testing was with a CSV file, however I get the same results using the following code.  So, isn't it possible to accomplish this task?  I have seen other posts where I would do my own looping and reading of the sections, but I am hoping that the nested C# classes will work.  It fits the requirements better.

I am sure that this example will be helpful to others.

Thank you for your help!

Mike

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using CsvHelper;
using CsvHelper.Configuration;

namespace CsvParserExample
{
    public class CsvParser
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
                {
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                        using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader))
                        {
                            // CsvFile.Name
                            writer.WriteLine("Mike,,");

                            // Section1.Id, Section2.Comment, Section2.Purpose
                            writer.WriteLine("1234,, I am a comment.,, I am a purpose.");
                            writer.Flush();
                            stream.Position = 0;

                            csv.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = false;
                            csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<CsvFileMap>();
                            csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<Section1Map>();
                            csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<Section2Map>();
                            csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<Section3Map>();

                            var recs = csv.GetRecords<CsvFile>().ToList();
                        }
                }
            }
        }

        public class CsvFile
        {
            public Section1 Section1 { get; set; }

            public Section2 Section2 { get; set; }
        }

        public sealed class CsvFileMap : CsvClassMap<CsvFile>
        {
            public CsvFileMap()
            {                
                References<Section1Map>(m => m.Section1);
                References<Section2Map>(m => m.Section2);
            }
        }

        public class Section1
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }

        public sealed class Section1Map : CsvClassMap<Section1>
        {
            public Section1Map()
            {
                Map(m => m.Name).Index(0);
            }
        }

        public class Section2
        {
            public string Id { get; set; }

            public Section3 Section3 { get; set; }
        }

        public sealed class Section2Map : CsvClassMap<Section2>
        {
            public Section2Map()
            {
                Map(m => m.Id).Index(0);
                References<Section3Map>(m => m.Section3);
            }
        }

        public class Section3
        {
            public string Comment { get; set; }

            public string Purpose { get; set; }
        }

        public sealed class Section3Map : CsvClassMap<Section3>
        {
            public Section3Map()
            {
                Map(m => m.Comment).Index(0);
                Map(m => m.Comment).Index(1);
            }        
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, 'reader' is being used: "using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader))"  :)

Comment: @LeiYang he's right, `reader` is used to create `csv` and `csv` is used.

Comment: Okay, so I think that I have figured it out...  I turned things around... 
 I created an instance of CsvFile and used CsvHelper to write the instance to a CSV file.  The result is sensible, but it isn't what I expected:

Comment: Created File's Content: 

Mikie,54321,I am a new comment.

So, it put all fields in the class and referenced classes on the same row, thus in a single record.  I expected that it would map the class across multiple rows, which represented the sections in my class.  So, it looks like manual parsing is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I think that I have figured it out... I turned things around... I created an instance of CsvFile and used CsvHelper to write the instance to a CSV file. The result is sensible, but it isn't what I expected.

Created File's Content: `Mikie,54321,I am a new comment`.I So, it put all fields in the class and referenced classes on the same row, thus in a single record. I expected that it would map the class across multiple rows, which represented the sections in my class. So, it looks like manual parsing is the way to go.